# Certain websites in chrome keeping computer awake by activating an audio stream, even if no sound is playing. Is there a way to disable it?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I was wondering why my computer randomly stays awake and found out that certain websites will trigger an audio stream in windows, despite no sound being played from said site.

For example, if you go to this [page from quizlet.com](https://quizlet.com/102106276/spanish-flash-cards/), and then type `powercfg -requests`, for me it will say

```
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[DRIVER] Realtek High Definition Audio (HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0298&SUBSYS_102806E4&REV_1001\4&a3ff4e8&0&0001)
An audio stream is currently in use.

AWAYMODE:
None.

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None
```

I'm assuming because they've got a lot of sound producing actions on the page. Is there a way to make the OS ignore chrome's requests to stay awake?

Comment: +1. I have the same question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1161596/how-to-prevent-google-chrome-from-keeping-computer-awake